# Getting the index of the selected textfield using pure js

Tags: javascript

```
<INPUT type="text" class="deb_count" name="debt[]" id="debt" onChange="check_deb(this)"/>
```

I have an array of textfields which are created dynamically. When the users clicks on the textfield i want to get the index of the clicked text field. If the users cliks on 3 textfield it should return index 2

Comment: can you provide how the html will look like?

Comment: sry fr the delay fellas

Answer (score 0):

```
var textfields = []; // your array with dom elements
// this function is bound to the click event
function onclick() {
    alert(textfields.indexOf(this)); // your index ecma5
}
```

if they are in order in the dom document in the same container than you can use:

```
$(this).index()
```

http://api.jquery.com/index/

EDIT:
based on your code you could have addRow function return row
and then this is how you get the index:

```
var row = addRow;
$(row).click(function () {
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

Comment: its returning -1 @David Buchbut

Comment: what's in your textfields array? is it the actual elements or jquery?

Comment: it will be helpful if you paste the code you are using to populate teh array